# Selecting neighboring cells by attribute math

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a jquery function that will step through a series of grid cells in my DOM and change their color.

I can select the first cell with this `$('#container [hex-row=x][hex-column=y]')`.

Next, I want to select the cell that is in the column above and and row behind. Something like `$('#container [hex-row=x-1][hex-column=y+1]')`.

I am assuming you can't do math on an attribute in the selector. I am new to this so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us some mark-up

Comment: Or you share the correct piece of code (html + js) or this should be closed by offtopic. Read this and then edit the question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it outside the quote marker, like this

```
$('#container [hex-row="'+(x-1)+'"][hex-column="'+(y+1)+'"]');
```

Comment: LOL.... Isn't it a little strange the question and all answers of it receiving a downvote? I ask myself why...

Answer (score -1):

As the selector is a string you can not directly calculate in it. But what you can do is append the calculated value to the string like this

```
$("#container[" + (your calculation here + "][" + (your calculation here) + "]");
```